# Delphi - Inheritance Chain in a Object Tree

Tags: delphi, oop, inheritance, tree

I am trying to have an inheritance chain, in a tree of Parent-Child objects.

Let's say I have a obj type A, which has an array of A's, but also an array B's. B is another object which has an array of C's. C is inheriting from A, but slightly modified version of A.
So I have:

```
type
A= class
   fArrayOfA : Array of A;
   fArrayOfB : Array of B;
end;

C= class(A)
//body
end;

B= class
   fArrayOfC : Array of C;
end;
```

It seems that the order of objects is important, and the Delphi compiler reads from the top to bottom. So the "Array of B;" in A gives an Undeclared Identifier, unless I put type B above A. But then I get the error for "Array of C" in B, since it doesn't know what C is.

Any idea if there is any identifier missing that will solve this? I tried splitting A into unit1, and B&C into unit2, now I have "Circular Reference"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what is called a "Forward class" definition;

```
TB = class; // Forward Class

TA = class(TSomething)
  .....
end;

TB = class(TSomething)
  .....
end;
```

It basically allows `TA` to know about `TB` before it was completely declared.

Go read [Classes and Objects (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes) in the Delphi help.

Comment: Didn't know I can do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Important to note, that the declarations need to be in the same `type` section.